# Ubuntu 16.04 Snapd error: Download snap "ubuntu-core" from channel "stable"

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, nextcloud

I try to use snap to install nextcloud but when I enter the command:

```
sudo snap install hello
```

or

```
sudo snap install nextcloud
```

I'll get following error:

```
    error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "ubuntu-core" from channel "stable" (Get https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/search?fields=anon_download_url%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha512%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Cicon_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Csnap_id%2Csupport_url%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin&q=package_name%3Aubuntu-core: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided)
```

I've read that it was a bug a year ago and is fixed but I have no idea how to solve it at the moment. Do you have any clues for me?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like snapd is not connected to the server.
Try to see if snapd is running properly. You can even try restarting snapd.

`systemctl restart snapd`

What device are you running it on? I experienced a similar issue in which the image was not compatible with the latest snap updates.

Comment: Cheers this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `sudo snap install core`? `ubuntu-core` snap is now called `core`.

Comment: I tried it but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which didn't let me do anything related to snap. It turns out the computer's clock was the problem (which was showing the wrong time). When I corrected the time by selecting 'automatically from the internet', it let me do sudo snap install core and others.
Hope this helps.